# Floating window on incoming call screen

Tags: android, incoming-call

I want show some info when somebody call me.
I have service. This service has registred broadcastreceiver. This receiver listen for android.telephony.TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED.
I'm able to show toast when my phone is unlocked, but when I have phone locked and someone is calling to me,a toast is not showing.
What is the best way to show some info when someone is call to me?

Update:
I created floating window which I open when phone is ringing.
This work very well, but window is not showing when phone is locked and someone is calling to me. When I picked up the call, floating window is there. Is here some way to show this foating window on lockscreen incoming call screen?
This is the way how I opening floating window:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    startService(new Intent(context, FloatingWindow.class));
                }
            }, 2000);
```

and this is my floatin window

```
public class FloatingWindow extends Service{

private WindowManager wm;
private LinearLayout ll;
private Button btnStop;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    btnStop = new Button(this);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams btnParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    btnStop.setText("Stop");
    btnStop.setLayoutParams(btnParameters);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams llParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(66, 255, 0, 0));
    ll.setLayoutParams(llParameters);

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams parameters = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(400, 150, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    parameters.x = 0;
    parameters.y = 0;
    parameters.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER;

    ll.addView(btnStop);
    wm.addView(ll, parameters);

    ll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        private WindowManager.LayoutParams updatedParameters = parameters;
        int x, y;
        float touchedX, touchedY;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    x = updatedParameters.x;
                    y = updatedParameters.y;

                    touchedX = event.getRawX();
                    touchedY = event.getRawY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    updatedParameters.x = (int) (x + (event.getRawX() - touchedX));
                    updatedParameters.y = (int) (y + (event.getRawY() - touchedY));

                    wm.updateViewLayout(ll, updatedParameters);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            wm.removeView(ll);
            stopSelf();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, so I solved it a year ago, but no one has yet written this question, so I will give my solution.

Here is how I open floating window:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, FloatingWindow.class));
    }
}, 1000);
```

And here, onCreate from my FloatingWindow Service

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    btnStop = new Button(this);

    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureListener());

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams btnParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    btnStop.setText("X");
    btnStop.setLayoutParams(btnParameters);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams tvParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams llParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 0, 0));
    ll.setLayoutParams(llParameters);

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

    View popup_view = ((LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.popup_window, ll, false);
    tvInfo = (TextView) popup_view.findViewById(R.id.message);
    tvInfo.setText(this.getMessage());

    ll.addView(popup_view);
    wm.addView(ll, params);



    ll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        private WindowManager.LayoutParams updatedParameters = params;
        int x, y;
        float touchedX, touchedY;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    x = updatedParameters.x;
                    y = updatedParameters.y;

                    touchedX = event.getRawX();
                    touchedY = event.getRawY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    updatedParameters.x = (int) (x + (event.getRawX() - touchedX));
                    updatedParameters.y = (int) (y + (event.getRawY() - touchedY));

                    wm.updateViewLayout(ll, updatedParameters);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    gestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(new GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            stopSelf();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
    });       
}
```

It work perfectly even on lock screen.